# Chainsaw chain spins after start until I hit the throttle

Tags: small-engine, two-stroke

Immediately after I start my chainsaw (Craftsman 358.350280), without holding the throttle, the chain moves fast. As soon as I press and release the throttle, it comes down to idle fine and the chain stops moving. Is this expected? It seems unsafe/I would think the chain wouldn't move until I hit the throttle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: First you should have the chain brake engaged when starting.

Comment: @SolarMike There is no brake on this saw as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Must be cheap to not have a chainbrake - a good safety device. All the saws I purchased Stihl, and now only Husquvarna have chain brakes as standard - even the electric one.

Comment: @SolarMike If you had your brake off, would the chain run until you pressed + released the throttle? I'm trying to understand if that's normal behavior or something is wrong (this is the first time I've monkeyed with the carburetor on an engine).

Comment: I upped the question because I have a stihl that behaves the same. Brake on it starts and burns the brake. Once started no break burn no more.

Comment: Then the low speed throttle setting is too high.

Comment: @SolarMike But it idles without spinning properly after the throttle has been pressed + released once. I would think if the L screw was set incorrectly it would spin every time it idled, not just immediately after starting?

Comment: Is there a throttle feature that causes the engine to rev higher on first start? Is a choke lever involved that disengages when the trigger is pulled and released?

Comment: @fred_dot_u 1) no idea, I guess that's what I'm asking :) 2) I am not starting with the choke on (i.e. a "warm start").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the online operation manual for that model product, I found the following:

**Starting a warm engine**

- Pull the choke/fast idle lever out to the full extent, then push the
  lever back in completely (to the OFF Choke position)
- Slowly press primer bulb 6 times.
- Pull the starter rope quickly with your right hand until the
  engine starts.
- Squeeze and release throttle trigger, allowing engine to idle.

This sequence of events, particularly the last line, implies that the starting sequence is performing as you describe and as expected.

Comment: Can you explain how/why that happens? If the throttle is not pressed, how does it rev so high? And why would they want the first thing that happens after start be an uncontrolled (hands are on the pull cord, etc.) chain spin??
Also, why would you need to pull (ON) then immediately push (OFF) the choke?

Comment: @DavidDoria Do you have your foot pressed down inside the handle while starting the chainsaw.  This is the usual starting position for the saws I have owned.  Left hand on the front grip.  Right foot holding the rear handle down on the ground and right hand pulling the rope.  Once started, the right hand is used to pull the throttle to drop fast idle while the right foot still keeps it firm to the ground.

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes, that's what I'm doing. So you're right it's not like this is *actually* dangerous, but I would have thought it would be designed such that if everything is tuned correctly, the chain doesn't move unless your hand is actively pulling the throttle.

Comment: Pulling the choke out latches the fast idle.  So for warm starts you don’t need the choke, but you want fast idle.  Pulling out then pushing back in turns the choke off, but the fast idle is still latched.

Comment: @HandyHowie Ah ha! I had a second problem that I thought was unrelated to this. Even when the engine was warm (actually NOT following the manual, I guess because I forgot because I didn't understand the purpose), I would choke it, pull once, then unchoke it and pull again to start. I just confirmed that the pull after the choke was unnecessary. If I indeed follow the choke out + in procedure, the engine starts and the chain spins. However, if I simply pull WITHOUT ever turning the choke on, the engine starts and idles WITHOUT the chain moving! Where can I learn more about "fast idle latching"?

Comment: @DavidDoria There is not much to learn.  When you pull the choke out, the fast idle is latched (locked) on.  If you try this with the engine off, you may hear the mechanism clicking.  When you then pull the throttle you will hear the fast idle click off.  The fast idle just makes starting easier, just like you used to add a bit of throttle when starting old motorbikes.